# How to run a batch file with user set for file access using icacls

Tags: icacls

I am trying to run icacls utility for sharing files. But I have a set of users A, B, C and D only for whom I would need to provide access. One way of granting access is to write n lines for n users. Is there any easier way to provide access to all users. The number of users are around 50.

Answer (score 0):

I always wonder why when there is a shared resource has been ignored groups. There is a shared resource - a group. After that, there is a group assembles resources (groups) and that it has any members. If we domain, great use OU, inter alia.

What are the benefits? For handling with the resources you do not subsequently change the level NTFS permissions. I only have a set of groups and users in groups. This is despite the large numbers of files in the shared resources makes instantaneous change permissions.

[image: Users, Group and Share]